# completely fit the toggle bar inside the div

Tags: javascript, css

my english is not very good, i hope i can explain what i want to say

I want to fit my toggle icon inside div. I couldn't do it, can you show me how to do it?

I want it to be shaped according to the size of the div. when the div shrinks, the toggle menu should also shrink

[image]

I want to make the image in the top image like the bottom image

[image]

```js
$(".menu").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
body {
background-color: black;
}

.btn5 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
.btn5 .icon {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  height: 8px;
  width: 60px;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: white;
}
.btn5 .icon:before {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  content: "";
  top: -20px;
}
.btn5 .icon:after {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  content: "";
  top: 20px;
}
.btn5.open .icon {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.btn5.open .icon:before {
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg) scaleX(0.75) translate(-20px, -6px);
}
.btn5.open .icon:after {
  transform: rotateZ(45deg) scaleX(0.75) translate(-20px, 6px);
}
.btn5:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="togg">
    <div class="menu btn5" data-menu="5">
      <div class="icon"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will get you closer to your second image. I changed up the structure a bit and just used a couple spans and positioned them absolute. You can tinker with the animation to your hearts content.

```js
$(".menu").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
body {
background-color: black;
}


.btn5 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 150px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.icon {
width:150px;
height:150px;
position: relative;
}

.btn5 .bar {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  position: relative;
  height: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
}

.bar:nth-of-type(1) {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.bar:nth-of-type(2) {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 left: 0;
}

.bar:nth-of-type(3) {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.menu.open .bar:nth-of-type(1) { 
transform: rotate(-45deg);
top: 10px;
left: -16px;
}

.menu.open .bar:nth-of-type(3) { 
transform: rotate(45deg);
bottom: 10px;
left: -16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="togg">
    <div class="menu btn5" data-menu="5">
      <div class="icon">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want it to be shaped according to the size of the div. when the div shrinks, the toggle menu should also shrink

Comment: May I ask how big you want it to be? Normally you want a clickable menu button to be around 45px by 45px so that it is the relative size of a finger tap. A screen will never shrink to a small enough size for it to start shrinking.

Comment: I want the divin to be positioned according to its size. when the div is 20 pixels, the buddha should be positioned to fit in the middle of the div according to him

Comment: Oh I know what you are saying. I am saying that the minimum size of the button for the menu should be 45x45 pixels. A screen will never shrink to the width where the menu button would need to shrink does that make sense?